# How to export a mysql SELECT to JSON, not as escaped text?

Tags: mysql, json, phpmyadmin, export

After trying different things for hours now it's starting to drive me nuts. So I really hope somebody here could help me with this.

I have a test select query which has only one field that is the result of `JSON_OBJECT()` function, so that should be JSON (no text). But whatever I try, phpMyAdmin keeps escaping the json keys on an export of the result grid. Which is obviously not what I want when exporting to JSON.

Just a simple example, this:
`SELECT JSON_OBJECT("key", "value") as json`, results into this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTUaI.png)
and exports to something like this:

```
{
    "json": "{\"key\": \"value\"}"
}
```

Which is obviously no valid json as key should be a key, not part of a string.

Is there somebody out there that could please tell me how to export json data as real json without acting like the output of `JSON_OBJECT()` is text, so without the wrong escapes?

Thanks in advance!!

Using:
- MariaDb 10.4.10
- phpMyAdmin 4.9.2

Comment: How exactly are you generating the export file within phpMyAdmin? Selecting the JSON format from the Export tab generates values that are IMHO correct (although in a format that I can't forsee using directly). A single row is exported as a key value pair with the entire row data being contained as the value for the exported item. So what I'm seeing in my test is a single row looking like `{"j":"{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"Monty\"}"}`. I believe the escapes are appropriate here because each of the escaped values is contained in the single value for key "j". Are you using some other export means?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch Thanks for your respond.
I'm exporting with row export to export the select output. I also tried it with exporting a view.
The output you get is not the output I would expect as it's not a LONGTEXT type, but JSON. If it would be LONGTEXT it would be right to excape keys and values as there are no keys and values, but just text according to sql. But now there's a JSON_OBJECT() so it should output JSON IMHO.
So: 
{
   "json: { "key": "value" }
}
Strange thing is that if you Copy instead of Export it doesn't escape the json. So it looks like an issue in the export to me

Comment: I'm not sure if we're talking about the same thing or two different things. "Copy" takes you to the insert data page, which is through the GUI and wouldn't need to escape values. When I export, each **entire row** is exported as one single JSON value. It seems to me that you're expecting each column to export as a key:value pair where the column name is the key and the contents are the value — but phpMyAdmin exports the entire row in one value, so all the double-quotes need to be escaped, since they are contained within that single value. Therefore, the escapes here seem correct to me.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch Sorry, we are talking about the same thing, but what you state about the json export just isn't true. The json export IS exporting key-value pairs (columnname - data) but should also export the JSON field as it's own SUB-object with key-value pairs and if it has deeper levels also export those as JSON.
That's the whole point of having a JSON object. Otherwise we could just use a LONGTEXT field.

Comment: Yeah, can only confirm what @Friksel is saying. Does anyone know the solution how to format this string into native Json? Can be done with js as well.